I cant make AWS Api Gateway redirect me to Cognito Hosted UI
all the tutorial video/blog i looked into do exactly the same thing, after they set up the api gateway and cognito userpool, they try to test there endpoint in api gateway and they of course get
message "Unauthorized"

because they need the token, they login in hosted UI and copy the JWT token "MANUALLY" btw, and it works, all the tutorial do this. i don't want to copy the JWT token and paste it every time. I am calling the api gateway endpoint.
I want api gateway to redirect me to hosted UI, I assume there is no way of doing this, if there is someone who knows this please help.
what i did

step 1 create HTTP API
step 2 added Integration target (my https resource server url)
step 3 created authorizer (JWT) and added Issuer URL (cognito Issuer URL)/ Audience (clientid)
final step added Authorization to my endpoints

now whenever I go to the url and invoke /emails or /something
message "Unauthorized"

I've read and watched videos like these, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7OHogUcRmI", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFSU6rhFETk&t=1016s" and more
